# PHP template/layout function

Tags: php, layout

I have this function but it's not good. It's making it hard to debug my code:

```
fun... {
    eval('?>' . str_replace(
        '{yield}',
        file_get_contents('templates/' . $template . '.phtml'),
        file_get_contents('templates/layouts/' . $layout . '.phtml')
    ));
}
```

Please let me know of better replacements.

Thanks.

Comment: looks like phpbb :) .. what are you specifically trying to address? this seems like a fairly vital piece of the function and load your template pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function render($template, $layout) {
    $cache = "wherever/you/put/the/cache/file/{$template}_{$layout}.phtml";

    if (!file_exists($cache)) {
        $template = file_get_contents('templates/' . $template. '.phtml');
        $layout = file_get_contents('templates/layouts/' . $layout . '.phtml');

        $output = str_replace('{yield}', $template , $layout);
        file_put_contents($cache, $output);
    } else {
        include($cache);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using output buffering is the best way for acheiving a filled template data

```
ob_start();
include "my/template/link.phtml";
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```